Can't request for data from node.js from unity
I am trying to request a data from a node.js server by feeding it jsondata from a unity script but the connection keeps failing and im not sure if it's my code issue. The api definitely works with the json data as I tried it in curl.
public IEnumerator Post(string url,string jsonData)
    {

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.PostWwwForm(url, jsonData))
        {
            www.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
            www.certificateHandler = new BypassCertificate();

            byte[] dataByte = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(jsonData);
            www.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(dataByte);
            www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            //if (expectedReturn != null) //always have download handler to handle error data being sent over
            www.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandlerBuffer)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            // Handle error
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle successful response
            Debug.Log("Response: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
        }
    }
}

// Class to bypass certificate validation
public class BypassCertificate : CertificateHandler
{
    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        // Always return true to bypass certificate validation
        return true;
    }
}


Please provide an error with a stack trace.
